# How can I dump UI hierarchy to a variable in Bash?

Tags: shell, scripts

I want to dump the output of `uiautomator dump` to a variable and read it from there. How can I edit the below script so as to achieve that?

```
#!/system/bin/sh
while true ;
do uiautomator dump
sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138169/discussion-on-question-by-jideofor5050-how-can-i-dump-ui-hierarchy-to-a-variable).